# Variant percentage daily, with a fixed maximum of days and percentage

Tags: javascript

I have a program that needs to add a special task, which is to add a payment, this payment varies from 1-2% daily on a specific value, this applying the following rules;

- The percentage of the payment must vary between 1-2%, it should not be the same every day. this percentage must be random, between 1-2%.
- The time of payment days is 200 days.
- Upon reaching day 200, the sum of the percentages given daily can not exceed 300% of the specific value.

Taking into account these data, I summarize the following;

Value: 100
percentage: 1-2% daily
Payment days: 200
Maximum percentage to pay: 300%

If the percentages could be fixed then you could divide the days of payment between the maximum percentage to pay something like `300% / 200 days` = `1.5%` per day, 'but unfortunately the rule would leave which the percentage can not be equal.

How could I have control over both parties, that is, give a percentage that varies from `1 - 2%` daily, but taking as for the missing days and without exceeding `300%` when the final day of payment arrives that would be the day 200

I would be very grateful for the ideas you can give me.

Comment: Hi f! Try the truth dividing the days to weeks, then calculate the percentage you played per week and make a random percentage between 1-2 the first and second day of the week, so subtract the percentage of the first two days to the percentage of the week, and the three days remaining to generate the percentages randon not greater than those that touched him per day, but discard this, apart from not being practical, honestly I am something new :(, that's why I asked for ideas to be able to apply them. answer <3

Answer (score 0):

- Use 1% for the first day's payment
- Add 0.005% for each successive day's payment

If you need these to be random, put them in a list and shuffle it.

Comment: Hello!! Thank you for your answer, I think it would not be very good option, because this would be payments with increasing percentages, and what is needed is to be totally random, or to simulate the randon.

Comment: Then you should update the question, which says *nothing* about needing anything to be random.

Comment: I just did it, thank you very much for your help, and apologize for the bad writing.